# Bootstrap TypeAhead.js prevent invalid entry

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I am using the bootstrap typeahead.js feature for autocomplete capability for 'state' lookup.  How can I best prevent individuals from typing all (and not successfully picking Alaska) before submitting the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeahead.js does not currently support this behavior.
You can use other libraries better suited for restricted options, for example [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)
However I have working fork of Typeahead that supports this.
See the JQuery example page here:
https://github.com/Svakinn/typeahead.js/blob/typeaheadSimple/Examples.md

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you could enforce picking from valid options only and clearing any invalid input.

Start with creating a custom `source` which tracks search results:

```
    var sync = false;
    var current_results = [];
    var current_q = '';
    var selected_val = '';

    function search(q, sync) {
        current_q = q;
        window.sync = sync;
        engine.search(q, cust_sync);
    }

    function cust_sync(datums) {
      current_results = datums;
      sync(datums);
    }

    $('#typeahead').typeahead(
        {
          highlight: true,
          minLength: 0
        },
        {
            source: search // custom search engine
        }

    );
```

Then bind `select` and `change` event handlers.

```
    $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:change', function(ev) {
        var current_val = $('#typeahead').val();
        // user moved cursor out of input without selecting from the menu
        if(current_val != selected_val){
            // current query has search results
            if(current_results.length)
                // change input to the first valid search result
                $('#typeahead').typeahead('val', current_results[0].name); 
            // no results for this query - clear input
            else 
                $('#typeahead').typeahead('val', '');
            }
    });


    $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
        selected_val = $('#typeahead').val(); // keep track of a selected value
    });
```